# Regex: Get anything before

Tags: c#, regex, ini

I'm coding my own .INI file reader and making it as expansive and fixed as possible to work in many situations.

The wiki says some programs use the ';' semicolon for comments, and some use '#' hash.

I'm trying to utilize Regex to remove comments on any lines' value, here's what I've come up with;

This is the INI text file:

```
t1 = t2
t3 = t4 ;test
t5 = t6 #test
```

The code in practice:

```
value = Regex.Match(value, ".*(?=;|#");
```

Which does work! But only get the second and third line.

The positive lookahead '(?=;|#")', how would I make it optional? (like, only if it contains the ';' or '#' then substring it), hopefully my goal here is clear, if not let me know.

Comment: If it's an optional lookahead, then the lookahead doesn't do anything.  What do you mean by "substring it"?

Comment: I want it to return anything before ';' or '#' if there's one there, if there isn't just return it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just this:

```
^[^;#]*
```

This will match every non- ; or # character from the beginning of the string. If ; or # are not present, everything will be matched. Otherwise it will match characters only up to ; or #.

If you don't want to match empty lines, use:

```
^[^;#]+
```

Comment: How would I reverse that? I have "[test]l=l" and I want to get "l=l" after the ']', but it also might not contain the "[test]"?

Comment: Very similar: `[^]]*$`

Comment: I can only post a question every 90 minutes.I'll paste what I wrote here though:

Comment: Hi, I have the string:

    "[test]t4=kdf8"

I want to grab "t4" after "[test]" and before "=kdf8", but "test" could be anything, and "kdf8" could be anything.

So far, using regex from @Szymon, I have:

    value = Regex.Match(value, "[^]]*$");

Which grabs the "t4=kdf8" part, now I wish to also grab just the "t4" part from that (all in one regex call), I'd rather not inefficiently use regex multiple times on a value just to break it down piece by piece.

Comment: This is a good use case for assertions - you want to match something between 2 characters ] and =: `(?<=]).*(?==)`

Comment: That only works if it contains the "[test]", some lines may not.

Comment: Nevermind, realized I only had to use '(?<=])?' with the '?' to match zero or more.

Comment: Though, with this string: " [ test ] s  =  l ", it's matching " [ test ] s " opposed to the desired " s ".